# Window Function w/ a case statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDAqx.png)Help for a newer SQL analyst: I need to get MAX value from the YearMo column by company, where Prem is zero/null. I created a flag to find YearMo where the sum is 0, indicated by a '1' in the exclude column.

How can I edit my current window function to include a case statement where it would not include YearMo's that have the flag.

The function: MAX("YearMo") OVER (PARTITION BY "Company") AS "MaxYearMo"

[Example Snip of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXFKS.png)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: `I need to get MAX value from the YearMo column by company, where Prem is zero/null` IS or IS NOT? Description does not match the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CASE expression to build conditional aggregation. "where Prem is zero/null" :

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Prem IS NULL OR Prem = 0 THEN "YearMo" END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY "Company") AS "MaxYearMo"
```

otherwise:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Prem <> 0 THEN "YearMo" END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY "Company") AS "MaxYearMo"
```